# Javascript - breaking a string into a formula

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

let's say I have an image, with this formula:

```
blabla.com/bla/twofive.hash.png
```

The above can be represented as a string in JavaScript.

I'd like to know how to build an array that will break every special sign (such as "." and "/"), and will contain something like this:

```
var arr =  ['blabla', 'com', 'bla', 'twofive', 'hash', 'png'];
```

so I can easily access any property of the array with a simple arr[number];

Answer (score 5):

simply try

```
"blabla.com/bla/twofive.hash.png".split(/[./]/) //outputs ["blabla", "com", "bla", "twofive", "hash", "png"]
```

Comment: @apokryfos not when it is inside `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'blabla.com/bla/twofive.hash.png'.split(/\.|\//);
```

Result:

```
["blabla", "com", "bla", "twofive", "hash", "png"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **[match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

```js
var res = "blabla.com/bla/twofive.hash.png".match(/[^./]+/g);
console.log(res);
```